# Java Akka Actors with parameters with Spring

Tags: java, spring, akka, actor

In my project, I have used as a code base the [Lightbend activator template](http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/akka-java-spring). It works perfect but the Actor in example is not created with parameters.

I need to create a new Actor and pass to it a parameter during construction such as :

```
getContext().actorOf(SpringExtProvider.get(actorSystem).props("ControllerActor",type), "controller_" + type)
```

In this use case, the controller needs to be able to be created with a props paremeter **type** which is used to typed (obviously) the controller. Each Actor is specifically design to handle and control a specific king of object depending on its type.

But I can't add a new parameter in the props method to pass this parameter. It is not working.

This is my code :

**SpringExtension.java**

```
package com.orange.spectre.core.akka.configuration;

import akka.actor.AbstractExtensionId;
import akka.actor.ExtendedActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Extension;
import akka.actor.Props;
import com.orange.spectre.core.config.SpringActorProducer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

/**
 * Created by Hervé Darritchon on 04/04/2016.
 * <p>
 * An Akka Extension to provide access to Spring managed Actor Beans.
 */
public class SpringExtension extends AbstractExtensionId<SpringExtension.SpringExt> {

    /**
     * The identifier used to access the SpringExtension.
     */
    public static SpringExtension SpringExtProvider = new SpringExtension();

    /**
     * Is used by Akka to instantiate the Extension identified by this
     * ExtensionId, internal use only.
     */
    @Override
    public SpringExt createExtension(ExtendedActorSystem system) {
        return new SpringExt();
    }

    /**
     * The Extension implementation.
     */
    public static class SpringExt implements Extension {

        private volatile ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        /**
         * Used to initialize the Spring application context for the extension.
         *
         * @param applicationContext
         */
        public void initialize(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        }

        /**
         * Create a Props for the specified actorBeanName using the
         * SpringActorProducer class.
         *
         * @param actorBeanName The name of the actor bean to create Props for
         * @return a Props that will create the named actor bean using Spring
         */
        public Props props(String actorBeanName) {
            return Props.create(SpringActorProducer.class,
                    applicationContext, actorBeanName);
        }

        public Props props(String actorBeanName, String type) {
            return Props.create(SpringActorProducer.class,
                    applicationContext, actorBeanName,type);
        }
    }
}
```

**SpringActorProducer**
    package com.orange.spectre.core.config;

```
import akka.actor.Actor;
import akka.actor.IndirectActorProducer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

/**
 * Created by Hervé Darritchon on 21/03/2016.
 */
public class SpringActorProducer implements IndirectActorProducer {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private final String actorBeanName;
    private final String type;

    public SpringActorProducer(ApplicationContext applicationContext,
                               String actorBeanName) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        this.actorBeanName = actorBeanName;
        this.type = null;
    }

    public SpringActorProducer(ApplicationContext applicationContext,
                               String actorBeanName, String type) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        this.actorBeanName = actorBeanName;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public Actor produce() {
        return (Actor) applicationContext.getBean(actorBeanName);
    }

    @Override
        public Class<? extends Actor> actorClass() {
        return (Class<? extends Actor>) applicationContext.getType(actorBeanName);
    }
}
```

I can't create an actor with a props parameter as it is possible basically with Akka like ([Documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.3/java/untyped-actors.html)) :

```
    public class DemoActor extends UntypedActor {

  /**
   * Create Props for an actor of this type.
   * @param magicNumber The magic number to be passed to this actor’s constructor.
   * @return a Props for creating this actor, which can then be further configured
   *         (e.g. calling `.withDispatcher()` on it)
   */
  public static Props props(final int magicNumber) {
    return Props.create(new Creator<DemoActor>() {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @Override
      public DemoActor create() throws Exception {
        return new DemoActor(magicNumber);
      }
    });
  }

  final int magicNumber;

  public DemoActor(int magicNumber) {
    this.magicNumber = magicNumber;
  }

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Object msg) {
    // some behavior here
  }

}

  system.actorOf(DemoActor.props(42), "demo");
```

If you can help me, it should be great !

Thanks.

Comment: Nice question; hope your efforts will pay out!

Comment: If you review the code in `SpringActorProducer` the constructor accepts the type parameter and stores it in the property but then the `produce` method that creates the actor does not use it.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure if what you are attempting is actually possible. By delegating actor creation to the Spring container my experience is that your approach to inject objects into your actor has to be using the Spring approach i.e. `@Autowired`. Instead of injecting the type into your actor to inform it which type of objects it can handle why not define mutliple different actors to handle each specific object type? You then route your objects to the correct actor to be processed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm agree with "nickebbitt". Not sure that it is spossible. And one of the way is to inject an implementation of magic number generator into the actor.
Furthermore, I wouldlike to suggest following IndirectActorProducer implementation:

```
public class SpringDIActor implements IndirectActorProducer {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringDIActor.class);

private Class<? extends Actor> type;
private Actor actorInstance = null;

public SpringDIActor(Class<? extends Actor> type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public SpringDIActor(Actor actorInstance) {
    this.actorInstance = actorInstance;
}

/**
 * This factory method must produce a fresh actor instance upon each
 * invocation. <b>It is not permitted to return the same instance more than
 * once.</b>
 */
@Override
public Actor produce() {
    Actor newActor = actorInstance;
    actorInstance = null;
    if (newActor == null) {
        try {
            newActor = type.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            LOG.error("Unable to create actor of type:{}", type, e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            LOG.error("Unable to create actor of type:{}", type, e);
        }
    }
    ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(newActor);
    return newActor;
}

/**
 * This method is used by [[Props]] to determine the type of actor which will
 * be created. This means that an instance of this `IndirectActorProducer`
 * will be created in order to call this method during any call to
 * [[Props#actorClass]]; it should be noted that such calls may
 * performed during actor set-up before the actual actor’s instantiation, and
 * that the instance created for calling `actorClass` is not necessarily reused
 * later to produce the actor.
 */
@Override
public Class<? extends Actor> actorClass() {
    return type;
}}
```

This allows you co create actors without direct accesing to SpringContext from any code as follows:

```
ActorSystem.create("system").actorOf(Props.create(SpringDIActor.class, DemoActor.class))
```

Then just to use @Autowired annotation into the DemoActor.

No additional annotation on DemoActor is not required.